# check if value exists in database and then head to another php page

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check that does the job_no the user key-in exists in the database. If yes, go to download.php if not echo something. But when I execute the code below, it goes to the download page whatever I enter for job_no. Does anyone know why it likes this?

```html
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
exit;}

require_once "config.php";

$key_in = $key_in_error=$not_found_job_no="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
    if(empty(trim($_POST["key_in"]))){
        $key_in_error = "Please enter job number.";
    } else{
        $key_in = trim($_POST["key_in"]);
    }   
 
 $sql="SELECT job_no FROM files WHERE job_no=?";
 if ($sql=1)
  {
      header("location: downloads.php");
  }  else{
                     
         echo"Not valid job number!";
          
         } 
                    
                
            
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how you accomplish it, but you should link `$_SESSION["username"]` to the `id` (`who` field in the DB) for the file. Once you're authenticated, this query should get only the files related to the logged in user:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files";
```

should be something like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE who = ?";
```

Where `?` is the parameterized value of `$_SESSION['username']`

A few security tips:

- USE PDO AND NOT MYSQLI - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- Some changes to your code will introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities. Using PDO prepared statements will help add a layer of security between user-input and the executed raw SQL queries
- Never trust user input, they can always change it
- Don't let the user supply a `who` in the upload POST. Let the log in user from `$_SESSION` supply this. Otherwise other users can interprit and upload files as other users
- Just because a file has a file extension that matches your whitelist, doesn't mean that file is actually that file type. Extensions are user provided on uploaded files, check mime-types of the uploaded file and validate both
- Files are available under `uploads/` which is accessible via the root of your server. This means someone with the filename can access the file. Move this outside of the document root, and read the file contents into the response as a stream to prevent information leakage through `GET` parameter/path manipulation
- Add validation that the `$_GET['fileid']` parameter actually matches the `$_SESSION['username']`. Otherwise, any user authenticated or not can change `?fileid=` and access any file, even those that don't belong to them

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer me. I actually not that focus on security because the files are actually for all the users' access. I just want to give them a new experience of receiving the files i.e. download themselves at any time but not wanting me to send them hardcopy one by one. And the id is just for them direct to their own ones.